# How to trigger a data-rel="back" button in JQuery Mobile 1.4.3 with javascript?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using "page widget" to implement a dialog in jquery mobile with `data-dialog="true"`, everything is fine, i can also back to the previous page with the back button. I have implemented some actions on the dialog and need to close the dialog page after the actions are done.

I have tried with 
`$("#page").dialog("close");` 
and 
`$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change","#previousPageId");` 
both haven't worked for me.
How can i trigger the back button on page dialog with javascript?

I am using jQuery mobile 1.4.3 and jQuery 1.11.1.
Thanks for your answer and any comments are welcome.

Comment: `$.mobile.back();` should work.

Comment: @Omar: you are the best, would you like to make your comment as an answer, so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dialog widget is deprecated as of 1.4, hence, `.dialog("close")` is no longer a valid function.

To go back to previous page:

- jQuery Mobile

  ```
  $.mobile.back();
  ```
- JavaScript

  ```
  window.history(-1)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', <pageid>, { reverse: false });
```

Reverse-option being true/false determines whet ever you are going backwards or forwards. True means back I think.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, unfortunately it is not working for the page.dialog extention. The suggestion from Omar does work for the page.dialog extention.

Comment: @YingdingWang Keep those options in mind though, or actually the way I showed as to how to use them - might come in handy at some point.

Comment: you are right. I will try this out for the pages. Thanks all the way.